# Detect verb is weak verb else strong verb

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

Description:
If a verb contains the d, ed,t at ending then we call it as a weak verb
and if any vowel change in the verb happens then we call it as a strong verb as per my understanding and mentioned in this link also **https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-between-a-weak-verb-and-a-strong-verb-1691036**. & **https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/strong-verbs-vs-weak-verbs** I have implemented and try to cover all the cases for detecting weak or strong verb
Please help me create an algorithm to detect weak verb by covering all test cases

```
from collections import Counter

def is_vowel(char):
    """
    check for char is vowel or not
    """
    return 'aeiou'.__contains__(char.lower())

def LetterCount(text):
    """
    Create the alphabet count dictionary using counter
    """
    return dict(Counter(c for c in text.lower() if c.isalpha()))


def change_vowel_detect(verb1, verb3):
    """
    Checking if the vowel is changing or not 
    input verb1 : verb base form (captured with lemmatization)
          verb3 : verb 3rd form (captured from sentence)
    return :
        status of change_vowel_bool and is_key_mismatch
    """
    change_vowel_bool = False
    is_key_mismatch = False
    verb1_count_dict = LetterCount(verb1)
    verb3_count_dict = LetterCount(verb3)
    print(verb1_count_dict,'\n',verb3_count_dict)
    for key,value in verb1_count_dict.items():
        #iterate over verb1 count dictionary
        if is_vowel(key):
            #checking verb character is vowel or not
            if key in verb3_count_dict:
                #checking same character is found in other verb dictionary or characters
                if verb1_count_dict[key] != verb3_count_dict[key]:
                    #if both the key count mismatch then status changes 
                    #print("word_count_missmatch")
                    change_vowel_bool  = True

            else:
                change_vowel_bool  = True
                is_key_mismatch = True
    return change_vowel_bool, is_key_mismatch

def is_weak_verb(verb1, verb3):
    #change_vowel_bool = False
    change_vowel_bool, is_key_mismatch = change_vowel_detect(verb1, verb3)
    week_verb_bool = False
    #if verb3.endswith('d') or verb3.endswith('t'):
    #week_verb_bool = True
    if verb1 == verb3:
        week_verb_bool = True
    if verb3.endswith('ed') and change_vowel_bool == False:
        week_verb_bool = True
    if (verb3.endswith('d') or verb3.endswith('t')) and is_key_mismatch == True :
        week_verb_bool = True
    return week_verb_bool

#testcases
print(is_weak_verb('Feed', 'Fed'))      # strong verb
print(is_weak_verb('love', 'loved'))    # Weak verb
print(is_weak_verb('meet', 'met'))      # Weak verb
print(is_weak_verb('put', 'put'))       # weak verb
print(is_weak_verb('wear', 'wore'))     # Strong verb
print(is_weak_verb('bring', 'brought')) # strong verb
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to need this for English, you may want to consider just using https://verbs.colorado.edu/~mpalmer/projects/verbnet.html
If you want to implement it yourself, good luck&have fun, but easy to get lost in a mighty long list of exceptions if you really want to cover *all* cases...

Comment: I checked for the link provided but I am not clear how to use for my problem statement can you elaborate on my code